# Word 2007 - "Save as" / Save dialog window won't show, even for unsaved documents

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-office-2007

I have a situation where when I try to save an unsaved document using Ctrl+S, or choosing File -> Save or File -> Save As, the save dialog window won't appear, so I can't save the document, and I have to copy it to Wordpad and save it from there and restart Word for the dialog to work again.

If I make changes to an existing document when this is occurring, Ctrl+S will save the changes, but I can't pull up the Save As dialog for that existing document either.  The open dialog also won't pull up, but the Print dialog and the New Document dialog will.  While this is happening, I can open Excel and use its Save As dialog just fine.

Any ideas how to solve or investigate this?

Comment: What happens when you press F12?

Comment: @Abraxas - the same thing - no dialog comes up.  By the way, I don't think this matters, but just in case it's helpful, in all cases when trying to save the cursor changes to the spinning wheel for a split second and then changes back to normal.

Comment: Assuming you are on Windows - go to Programs and Features , select Microsoft Office 2007, press enter and select modify/repair and run the repair on your Office installation. This shouldn't take too long and fixes a great many issues.

Comment: Doing repair from there failed so I ran repair from the DVD which worked.  I'll plan to report back if it occurs again, though it might be weeks before I know for sure. Thanks

Comment: Great! Glad it was fixed. I added an answer based on that comment for anyone who ends up finding this question. Feel free to mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Abraxas Oh, maybe my wording wasn't clear.  Doing the repair from the DVD succeeded at completing the repair whereas control panel failed, but I won't know whether the problem is fixed yet or not since it doesn't always occur.  I've set a reminder for a month from now to come back.

Comment: The issue is occurring again, so apparently the repair install didn't fix it. I'll plan to reinstall per the next step you mentioned in your answer.